# What happens when angular v7 project has both angular-cli.json and angular.json?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working on angular v7 project, and someone by mistake while resolving conflicts, committed angular-cli.json. Now I'm not facing any problems in building/serving application. But still, I want to know what happens when angular v7 project has both angular-cli.json and angular.json?

Comment: Basically nothing will change or make conflict since angular-cli.json was used by angular v5 where angular.json is used by angular v6+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLTR;**
If you are using Angular CLI v6+ and for some reason file `.angular-cli.json` appearing in your project - simply delete it as it is not in use anymore.

**Explanation**:

In early versions of Angular CLI (v1-v5) they used `.angular-cli.json` for configuration. Later on (v6) `.angular-cli.json` was replaced with different format `angular.json` called [Angular Workspace](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config).

If you migrate from early versions to the latest versions, Angular CLI will do an automatic migration for you so it converts your `.angular-cli.json` to `angular.json`

> The `.angular-cli.json` configuration file is replaced with `angular.json`
>   workspace file, a new file the lays the foundation for multiple
>   projects in a single workspace.
>
> In this file you can find every configuration item and default that
>   Angular CLI uses. Having all configuration on file allows you to avoid
>   typing out multiple configuration flags on each command and npm
>   script. ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases?after=v6.1.0-rc.1

Answer (score 2):

Angular 6.0+ version is not read the angular-cli.json. For more information please refer to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases?after=v6.1.0-rc.1) link. Hope this helps.